# Two forms that has the same routes but should redirect to different pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have created a modal. Inside a modal is a form. I have used this modal in Two pages.
When i click on submit in the modal-form on the second page it redirects to the first page.
I don't want that to happen. I want it to redirect to its own page.

```html
<form action="{{route('asd')}}" method="post">
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="procurement_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-rigth">PROCUREMENT MODE 
   </label>
   <input id="procurement_name" type="text" name="procurement_name" class="col-md-9 form-control" form="sub-form" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-around">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" form="sub-form" style="font-size: 25px;">SAVE PROCUREMENT MODE</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you tried `return back();` ?

Comment: I will suggest you set a hidden value in the both forms with the url you want to redirect to. The in your controller, just do `retrun redirect($request->input_name_for_hidden_url)`

Comment: but how can i get the URL?

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

just add one hidden input

`<input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="www.google.com">`

and base upon that you can redirect from controller

```php
<form action="{{route('asd')}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="www.google.com">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="procurement_name" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-rigth">PROCUREMENT MODE
        </label>
        <input id="procurement_name" type="text" name="procurement_name" class="col-md-9 form-control" form="sub-form"
            required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row justify-content-around">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" form="sub-form" style="font-size: 25px;">SAVE
            PROCUREMENT MODE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

inside Controller

`retrun redirect($request->redirectUrl) // then you can redirect`

Comment: Thanks i tried to do that. but didn't work out for me

Comment: what you have tried and error you are getting ..? this is not exact code this is just a demo you have to adjust with your code

Comment: Thanks for your concern, really. but i have solve the error.. inspired by your idea.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Everyone but i have solve my problem..

```html
switch ($request->redirectUrl){
    case 'procurement':
          return redirect(route('procurement.index'));
          break;
    default:
          return redirect(route('purchaseOrder.create'));
          break;
}
```